# Why does my program keep repeating the else loop?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

Else loop repeating although conditions are met.

```
import time

def main():
    print("Welcome to the teaching system")
    login()

def login():
    input("What is your password?")
    if input == "1234":
        print("Login successfull...")
    else:
        print("Try again")
        time.sleep(3)
        main()

main()
```

if you input the correct password '1234' it skips and enters the else loop. Tried using Quotation marks (''), Speech marks ("") and nothing has changed. Is anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Your else statement is not in a loop

Comment: Your program is recursive and calls `main()` which calls `login()` again. The `else:` is executed because the function `input` is never equal to any string.

Comment: Read on how to use input in python

Comment: You are not retaining the result of calling `input()` and you are then comparing the `input` function against "1234".

Answer (score 0):

You should save the input in a variable and use that when comparing to your string like this for example:

```
import time

def main():
    print("Welcome to the teaching system")
    login()

def login():
    password = input("What is your password?")
    if password == "1234":
        print("Login successfull...")
    else:
        print("Try again")
        time.sleep(3)
        main()

main()
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps as a learner. Still trying to grasp the basic concepts.

Answer (score 0):

`input` is a function that *returns* a string from standard input. You need to save that value, rather than assume that the name of the function can be used as a variable holding the last string typed. (`input` *is* a variable, but it's value is the function itself, not the last return value of the function.)

And don't use (mutual) recursion to implement a loop.

```
def login():
    while True:
        passwd = input("What is your password?")
        if passwd == "1234":
            print("Login successfull...")
            break
        print("Try again")
        time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move your input prompt into if statement:

```
import time

def main():
    print("Welcome to the teaching system")
    login()

def login():
    if input("What is your password?") == "1234":
        print("Login successfull...")
    else:
        print("Try again")
        time.sleep(3)
        main()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
import time


def main():
    print("Welcome to the teaching system")


def login():
    if password != '1234':
        print('Try again')
        time.sleep(3)
    else:
        print("Login successfull...")

main()
password = input("What is your password?")
login()
while password != '1234':      
    main()
    password = input("What is your password?")
    login()
```

The loop that plays if you guessed the wrong password plays outside the function until the guess is correct. Hope I helped!